# Linux and Tablet PC

Tags: linux, tablet

I am a proud owner of a Motion M1400 tablet, currently running Debian Sid.
I want to improve the Tablet feel of the machine, so I am looking for some extension apps, like:

- Handwriting notebook (with some extensions for recognizing mathematical and physical formulas, copy-paste and selection move, pressure based pens, custom setup of drawing pens, saving into well known formats like PDF, or OneNote's workbook format)
- A nice control panel for tablet use (huge icons and text, something like the MeeGo UI)
- Those nice Ubuntu additions what enables proper keyboard on GOK (not only the buttons of right-click), and makes password popups into normal windows to be used with on-screen keyboard, and also, the bottom-docked keyboard on the unlock window after resuming)
- Anything what can improve Tablet usage

And no, Ubuntu will not be good, even the latest betas are overdriving the graphical accelerator of the M1400 thus overheating it.

Answer (score 0):

[sketching and PDF-/picture-annotating](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jarnal/) sketching and PDF-/picture-annotating. It works like a normal notepad with the difference of being digital. It is thought to be used with a stylus on tablet-pcs.

After a month or so, Debian stable will be "Squeese", so there is a special KDE version for netbooks/tablets

they also have nice plasmoid for retractable onscreen keyboard (you can adjust size and position)